# Error occurred in sonar execution using ant

Tags: java, spring, ant, sonarqube

Hi I am trying to execute sonar using ant script, the application is using spring core as well custom library.Ant build has no problem in compiling code, but during sonar analysis i am getting below exception:

```
     org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectExclusions.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectExclusions@f590bb, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.delegateExecution(SonarTask.java:208)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectExclusions.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectExclusions@f590bb, java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.picocontainer.monitors.NullComponentMonitor.lifecycleInvocationFailed(NullComponentMonitor.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:115)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:67)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:68)
    at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:106)
    at org.sonar.ant.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:210)
    at org.sonar.ant.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.delegateExecution(SonarTask.java:205)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapper
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.monitorAndThrowReflectionLifecycleException(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:130)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectExclusions.key(ProjectExclusions.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectExclusions.start(ProjectExclusions.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    ... 36 more
```

I am not able to understand the issue in the script, Can anyone please suggest me the solution of it?

Comment: Can you provide sonarqube version and plugins versions ?

Comment: sonar version is 2.11 RC3, we are using company sonar server for analysis, and it is working fine for other java projects(eclipse RCP etc). but in the spring project it is throwing the exception